# gulp karma test TypeError: Server is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, gulp, karma-runner

Trying to run karma using gulp for running tests but after following the example from: https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma

My gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var Server = require('karma').Server;

/**
 * Run test once and exit
 */
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
  new Server({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
  }, done).start();
});

/**
 * Watch for file changes and re-run tests on each change
 */
gulp.task('tdd', function (done) {
  new Server({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'
  }, done).start();
});

gulp.task('default', ['tdd']);
```

after I run: gulp test I get the Error:

```
TypeError: Server is not a function at Gulp.<anonymous>
```

Any suggestions of what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that karma-cli npm module wasn't properly installed globally. Running: `npm install -g karma-cli` solved the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Which version of karma do you have installed?

The API has changed from [`0.12`](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/dev/public-api.html) to [`0.13`](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/dev/public-api.html) and the example you've shown is the one for `0.13`.

The previous API was the following:

```
var server = require('karma').server;

//... more code
server.start( { .... } , function(exitCode){
  // ...
});
```

Comment: This helped me running karma from grunt; to use grunt-karma@0.12.1 you need karma ~0.13. I was also getting the `Warning: Server is not a function` messages.

Comment: I was using Karma + Gulp with latest versions